# Combinatorics identity; proof of $\sum_{n≥0}\left[\binom{n}{m}(z^n)\right]=\frac{z^m}{(1-z)^{m+1}}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am working on a proof and I came across a combinatorial identity on the internet that would really help me, but I cannot prove it. The identity is:

$$\sum_{n≥0}\left[\binom{n}{m}(z^n)\right]=\frac{z^m}{(1-z)^{m+1}}$$

I imagine it has something to do with the binomial theorem, but I just cannot figure it out. So, I am hoping that someone can either tell me what this identity is or help me prove it.

Comment: It's the binomial theorem for negative integer exponents.

Comment: Note that $$\sum \binom{n}{m} z^n = \sum \binom{n + m}{m} z^{n + m} = z^m \sum \binom{n + m}{m} z^{n}.$$